# How to show Bokeh graphs on the output of a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm trying to plot Bokeh graphs on the integrated Jupyter notebook in Pycharm. In the output, I get a message saying *'Output type is currently not supported'*.

This of course works when I open the notebook in my browser; however, I'd like to remain within Pycharm.

It would be great if somebody has found any solution or hack to this problem.

I'm currently using *Pycharm Professional 2019.1.*

Comment: There's no workaround I believe at the moment, but please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharms bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35121